# How to block sites like facebook.com, google.com etc. for different users

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, web-filtering

I use iptables for other sites as:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o EXTERNAL_IF -m owner --uid-owner USERNAME -d DESTINATION_WEB -j REJECT
```

It works for most sites except ones having a large range of IPs. What is the best way to achieve this? Please note that I need different rules for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Iptables isn't very good at this - you'd need to block every IP address that these sites use (and there are many). A better solution would be to use a proxy server. [Quintolabs.com](http://www.quintolabs.com) has a very nice and powerful squid/icap based implementation that will do exactly what it is that  you seek.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to achieve this is to install squid proxy, group users you want blocked form such sites in a group that redirects such sites to 127.0.0.1 to display blocked site message.

You can look at the [ACL wiki](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl) for squid, for details.